# Extract specific Data values from Invoices PDF using PDFminer : Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf, data-extraction, pdfminer

Looking out to extract only the specific data from the multiple PDF having different structures,

**I have stored all the pdf into invoice folder.**
I have tried to extract the data from the pdf using pdfminer library.

```
def extract_text(pdf_path):
    text21 = ''
    for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
        text21 = text21 + str(page[:-1]) + ' '
    return text21


inv = glob.glob(path+"/Invoice/*.pdf")

for i in inv:
    print(i)
    page = extract_text(i)
    print(page)
    data1 = str(page)
    lan = len(data1)

     x = re.search("Invoice Number:", page)
    x1 = re.search("Invoice No:", page)
    x2 = re.search("Bill No:" , page)
    x3 = re.search("Bill:" , page)
    if (x or x1 or x2 or x3):
        if x:
            yo = x.end()
        elif x1:
            yo = x1.end()
        elif x2:
            yo = x2.end()
        elif x3:
            yo = x3.end()
```

Similarly looking to append the Invoice Date, Total Bill Amount from the invoice PDF files. How i can append all the values into separate variables as extracted values to be used by some other process.

Answer (score 0):

using [pText](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release)

```
with open("input.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
    l = RegularExpressionTextExtraction("Invoice Number :[0-9]+")
    doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])

# do something with these events
l.get_matched_text_render_info_events_per_page(0)
```